# Sum of the series $2+5+14+41+......$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we find sum of the following series upto $n$ terms?

$S=2+5+14+41+.....$

As I can see, pattern here is:

$5=3(2)-1$

$14=3(5)-1$

$41$=3(14)-1

Is it possible to find sum of $n$ terms?

Comment: It is much more helpful to recognize that this series is $2$ plus the standard geometric series with constant ratio $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Look for a formula for the difference between consecutive terms.